# addLangs() is always empty

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngx-translate

I'm trying to populate the `addLangs()` method which accepts the string array from the `ngx-translate` package.

But everytime when I try to put the data coming from a service it always remains empty.

I tried everything but couldn't able to see why it is happening.
Its a small code but yet something is missing.
But when I try to fill the hardcoded string array that is being successfully filled inside it.

```
this.userService.getLangauges().subscribe((s: Array<any> = []) => {
  s.forEach((e) => {
    this.languages.push(e.name);  
  });
});

console.log(this.languages);  // I can see all the languages in console here

// let s = [
//   "en",
//   "sv-SE",
//   "da-DA",
//   "de-DE"
// ]
this.translate.addLangs(this.languages); // this is coming as empty
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using `this.languages` outside the `subscribe` function, which cause the `this.translate.addLangs(this.languages);` to be executed always before pushing the langs that you get from `userService` into your `languages` array.

So to resolve this, you have to wait until the langs pushed to your `languages` array, or simply move this part to be within `subscribe` function like the following:

```js
this.userService.getLangauges().subscribe((s: Array<any> = []) => {
    s.forEach((e) => {
        this.languages.push(e.name);
    });

    // here you have to call addLangs function.
    this.translate.addLangs(this.languages);
});
```